# How to mass change many files names using find and mv

Tags: command-line, batch-rename

I have a lot of files in many directories that are wrongly spelled.

They are spelled `Localisation.json` and I want to change them to `Localization.json`.

I tried this, but it does not work:

```
find -type f -name Localis* | xargs mv Localization.json
```

Answer (score 13):

#### Notice

**First**, `find -type f -name Localis* | xargs mv Localization.json` will never work ... You need something like `xargs -I {} mv {} Localization.json` or set the `xargs`'s option `-n 1`.

**Second**, `mv` is not the right choice here as it will result in all files named e.g. `Localisation.json`(*or whatever files `find` matches and outputs*) in all sub-directories of the current working directory moved to the current working directory and renamed as `Localization.json` overwriting this file every time ... e.g. `find` might output something like `./subdirectory/Localisation.json` and that will translate with `mv` like so:

```bash
mv ./subdirectory/Localisation.json Localization.json
```

changing destination directory to the current working directory ... You, definitely, don't want that.

Therefore, ...

#### Suggestion

You can format `find`'s output to be NULL delimited(*To try to avoid breaking filenames containing e.g. whitespace*) with `-print0` then pipe it to `xargs -0` with `rename` like so:

```bash
find -type f -name "Localisation.json" -print0 | xargs -0 rename -n 's/Localisation\.json$/Localization.json/'
```

Or. even better, and comparatively efficient ... you can use `find`'s own `-exec` with `rename` like so:

```bash
find -type f -name "Localisation.json" -exec rename -n 's/Localisation\.json$/Localization.json/' {} \+
```

and it's important to quote the argument to `-name` e.g. `-name "Localis*"`

Notice that everything in the `CurrentName` part of `rename`'s `'s/CurrentName/NewName/'` is considered a regular expression ... Hence the escaped dot `\.` to match a literal `.` and the `$` to match the end of the line excluding directories from being renamed in case you have a parent directory with the same filename e.g. `Localisation.json/Localisation.json`(*That can also be achieved with the `rename`'s option `--nopath`*)

The `rename`'s option `-n` will **only simulate** renaming ... Remove it when satisfied with the output to do the actual renaming.

#### Workaround

You can use `find`'s `-execdir`(*Which runs the specified command from the subdirectory containing the matched file*) with `mv` like so:

```bash
find -type f -name "Localisation.json" -execdir echo mv -n -- {} Localization.json \;
```

You can, also, use `find`'s `-exec` with `mv` in a `bash` command string utilizing `bash`'s parameter expansion and achieve the same result like so:

```bash
find -type f -name "Localisation.json" -exec bash -c 'echo mv -n -- "$1" "${1/%Localisation.json/Localization.json}"' _ {} \;
```

That will do **only a renaming dry-run(simulation)** ... Remove `echo` when satisfied with output to do the actual renaming.

Alternatively in `bash`, you can use recursive shell globbing and parameter expansion with only `mv` to achieve the same result like so:

```bash
shopt -s globstar; for f in **/Localisation.json; do
    # Renaming dry-run(simulation) ... Remove "echo" when satisfied with output to do the actual renaming.
    echo mv -n -- "$f" "${f/%Localisation.json/Localization.json}"
done; shopt -u globstar
```

Comment: Not sure whether quoting the argument of `-name` with double quotes is a good idea. You do not want the shell to expand the wildcards. You want to pass the argument unchanged to `find`. So use single quotes.

Comment: @vanadium Thank you for your feedback ... But no ... It won't be expanded by the shell when double quoted(*or single quoted ... Same behavior*) ... You can verify that if you enable bash command tracing with `set -x` then run it to see that it is passed to `find` without shell expansion :-)

Comment: Strange! Why does't the shell expand? It likely will if multiple files present in the current directory match, and then you will have a problem ;)

Comment: @vanadium Also no :-) ... It will be passed to `find` in single quotes both-ways ... So no shell expansion is going to happen that way in our lifetimes AFAIK :-) ... The shell expansion will, however happen **only** if not quoted at all and globs present in the filename.

Comment: I see, wildcards are only expanded when outside of any quotes - it is variables that are being expanded when within double quotes.

Comment: To get around the problem of `mv` moving everything to the current working directory, use `-execdir`

Comment: @muru Added that ... Thank you for your feedback.

Comment: +1 for providing safe solution: "*The rename's option -n will only simulate renaming ... Remove it when satisfied with the output to do the actual renaming.*" The mark of a true professional.

Answer (score 4):

In most cases, the easiest and most efficient way to rename files is by the command `rename`. To do it recursively within *Bash shell* you need to enable the *globstar* option:

```bash
shopt -s globstar
```

Then you can use the `rename` command in this way:

```bash
rename -n --nopath 's/Localisation\.json/Localization.json/' **/*
```

- Remove the `-n` option to disable the dry-run mode and do the actual rename.

You might want to disable the *globstar* option afterwards for good measures with:

```bash
shopt -u globstar
```

The above `rename` command should work out of the box (without enabling additional options) in *Zsh shell*.

However, although less efficient this way *as `mv` must be invoked for every single argument*, you can pipe `find`'s output to `xargs` with `mv` in a `sh` command string like so:

```bash
find -type f -name 'Localisation.json' -print0 | xargs -0 -I {} -- sh -c 'echo mv -n -- "$1" $(dirname "$1")/Localization.json' _ {}
```

`echo` is for dry-run only. Remove `echo` when satisfied with the output to do the actual renaming.

Comment: I did not refresh the page so didn't notice your answer :-D ... Removed that part anyway ... +1 and you might find the rename's option `--nopath`  useful.

Comment: Thanks, @Raffa. I will add a note about `--nopath` later. Meanwhile I also have upvoted your answer :) In addition I've realized the task could be solved by `find` and `xargs`, but the command is far complicated and I don't have time to explain it today: `find . -type f -name 'Localisation.json' -print0 | xargs -n1 -0 -I@ -- sh -c 'echo mv @ $(dirname @)/Localization.json'`  (remove `echo`)... so if you have time feel free to include it in your answer or throw a new one :)

Comment: That's nice but you're overloading it with options ... I think `find -type f -name 'Localisation.json*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I@ -- sh -c 'echo mv @ $(dirname @)/Localization.json'` will do fine :-) and it's smart ... I like it

Comment: It would be better to run the command just on the files that need renaming. Now if there's a file called `BritishLocalisation.json`, it will get renamed, too. And if you limit the command to files called exactly `Localisation.json`, a simpler expression would suffice so you don't have to repeat the filename: `rename -n s/s/z/ **/Localisation.json` :)

Comment: I had some free time and edited your answer with your comments ... I hope I didn't miss something :-)